# Software to update and license own product for custumers

Tags: java, software-development, c#, web-server, server

I am looking for a solution, that is able to to the following:

- Rollout updates of self developed software(written in C# and java) and install it automaticly or on demand
- Rollout updates for windows
- Rollout updates for external programs like VLC-Player
- Stop updates, if the license has expired
- Store information about licenses
- Ability to create and validate licenses

I know that there are a lot solutions to find on google, but maybe my research wasn't as good as it could be, so i would be happy, if there are some recommondations of you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time: one for Java libraries to achieve what you want and another for C#.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at WinGUP, http://wingup.org/, a GPLed updater written by Don Ho, the author of Notepad++. If you can update Notepad++, you can update almost anything, I should think.

If you have Notepad++ installed, you have WinGUP in the updater subdirectory in the root of the Notepad++ installation.

/s/ OTC